# how to select the 3 most recent months?

Tags: sql-server, select

I want to get the result for the 3 most recent months. and this is what I've create so far:

```
SELECT 
    year([date]) as tahun, 
    month([date]) as bulan, 
    [type] as tipe,
    SUM([net qty]) total_karton, 
    CAST(SUM([cm1 (rp)]) as decimal) as total_uang
FROM 
    tbl_weeklyflash_ID
GROUP BY 
    year([date]), 
    month([date]),
    [type]
ORDER BY 
    month([date]), [type]
```

but that query shows all months, how to get only the 3 most recent months?

Comment: Do you mean always October, November and December? Or just "the 3 most recent months"?

Comment: just the 3 most recent months :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `WHERE` clause, something like:

```
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(month,[date],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) between 0 and 2 --May have to adjust the end value on this
```

`2` will give you the current month and the previous 2. If you want 3 *whole* months of data, you might need to adjust the end value.

[`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) always gives the number of *transitions* that have occurred, for the date part specified. So in the above, it's counting the number of times that the month has *changed* between `date` (not a great column name, BTW) and the current date.

Comment: @Darmien_The_Unbeliever thank you, it works. now I get it. thanks you for your answer and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
WHERE month([date]) between month(getdate()) -3 and month(getdate())
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works but I need to adjust `3` to `2` so I can get what I want. thanks :)